# How to get clicked element datas inside React Bootstrap Modal?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-bootstrap

I have a problem with getting the current clicked element's data's from the API and displaying it inside React Bootstrap Modal body. The parent component is TopMovies.js which looks like:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import TopMoviesModal from '../top-movies-modal/TopMoviesModal';
const TopMovies = ({ currentMovies }) => {
const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

const showModal = () => {
    setIsOpen(true);
};

const hideModal = () => {
    setIsOpen(false);
};

const renderMovies = () => {
    if (Object.keys(currentMovies).length && currentMovies.length) {
        return (
            <div className="movies-labels-container">
                {currentMovies.map((movie) => {
                    return (
                        <div className="movie-label"
                            key={movie.id.attributes['im:id']} title={movie['im:name']['label']}
                            onClick={showModal}>
                            <img className="movie-img" src={movie['im:image'][2]['label']} alt={movie['im:name']['label']} />
                            <br />
                            <div className="text-under">
                                <span id="movie-title">{movie['im:name']['label']}</span>
                                <br />
                                <span id="movie-subtitle">{movie.category.attributes.term}</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    );
                })}
            </div>
        );
    }
};

return (
    <section className="top-movies-list">
        <div className="container-outter">
            <div className="container-fluid">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12" id="top-movies-module">
                        <div className="top-movies-container">
                            <h1 className="container-title">
                                TOP 100 movies
                            </h1>
                            {renderMovies()}
                            <TopMoviesModal
                                currentMovies={currentMovies}
                                hideModal={hideModal}
                                isOpen={isOpen} />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section >
)}
export default TopMovies;
```

and the child component TopMoviesModal.js which looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import Modal from "react-bootstrap/Modal";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";

const TopMoviesModal = ({ currentMovies, hideModal, isOpen }) => {

const renderMoviesDetails = () => {
    if (Object.keys(currentMovies).length && currentMovies.length) {
        return (
            <div>
                {currentMovies.map((movie, index) => {
                    return (
                        <div className="movie-label" key={movie.id.attributes['im:id']}>
                            <span id="movie-title">{movie['im:name']['label']}</span>
                        </div>
                    );
                })}
            </div>
        );
    }
};


return (
    <Modal
        show={isOpen}
        onHide={hideModal}
        size="lg"
        aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
        centered
    >
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-vcenter">
                Modal heading
        </Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
            {renderMoviesDetails()}
        </Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
            <Button onClick={hideModal}>Close</Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
    </Modal>
);}
export default TopMoviesModal;
```

Could you help me to solve this problem? I would be very grateful, thanks a lot

Comment: can you describe more about the problem and expected behavior

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how to get current clicked element. There's an array of objects and I have to click on the movie label and get displayed modal with this movie's datas (like title, description and so on). I know that there was sth like a second argument to the .map(el, index) function - like "index", which could help to get currently clicked element.. But I forgot how to do this